# Google App Engine WEB-INF and META-INF

Tags: java, google-app-engine, war, web-inf, meta-inf

When you create a new **Web Application Project** using the Google-Eclipse plugin, it creates an entire project directory structure for you, including:

```
src/
    META-INF/
        jdoconfig.xml
        persistence.xml
war/
    WEB-INF/
        lib/
        web.xml
        ...etc.
```

First off, my *understanding* was that `META-INF/` was only for utility JARs, not for web apps (WARs). So to see `src/META-INF/*` in the project caught me by surprise. But then I've seen examples of GAE web apps that package like so:

```
TheWebApp.war/
    WEB-INF/
        lib/
        classes/
            META-INF/
        web.xml
        ...
    blah.jsp
    ...etc/
```

With `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/`! On top of this, I don't see any mention of GAE projects and a `MANIFEST.MF` directory, which I always see used packaged under `META-INF`. Now I'm *really* confused.

So I think I first need confirmation/clarification on what the role of `META-INF` and `WEB-INF` are in general, then understand how they can be used together inside the WAR of *any* web application, and then understand any idiosyncrasies (if they exist) that GAE places on its WAR structures.

**Note:** I'm not using Maven and don't intend to for at least the next 6 - 12 months (I just don't have time to learn it right now). So if any of the answers to these questions depend on whether you're using a Maven-based buld or not, I'd prefer the non-Maven answers as I'm using Ant/Ivy.

So I ask:

1. What are the normal contents of a `META-INF` directory, for utility (library) JARs, executable JARs and WARs? Is a `MANIFEST.MF` necessary for WARs (GAE- and non-GAE alike), why or why not?
2. Where am I supposed to put non-web resources so that their available to the runtime classpath? For instance, say I have `environment.properties` or `myapp-custom-resource-config.xml`...where do I put these? In `WEB-INF/`, `WEB-INF/classes`, `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF`? Somewhere else?
3. What are the proper contents of a GAE project's `WEB-INF` and `META-INF` directories, and what's the correct way of packaging them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like JAR file META-INF directories, the root-level /META-INF directory contains the application manifest file. It can also contain resources for specific web containers or application servers. For example, Apache Tomcat looks for and uses a context.xml file in this directory to help customize how the application is deployed in Tomcat.

Unlike JAR files, the root-level /META-INF directory is not on the application classpath. You cannot use the ClassLoader to obtain resources in this directory. /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF, however, is on the classpath. You can place any application resources you desire in this directory, and they become accessible through the ClassLoader.